# Building an 2d html5 canvas game, and trying to connect to a server with javascript in order to create player "highscores."

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax, html5-canvas

After looking around on a Google without any success, i feel posting here may be a good idea as I have used this site to answer previous questions.

Anyways, I am currently working on an HTML5 canvas game using; 
`PHP, MYSQL, Html5, and JavaScript`.

I have `MYSQL` databases setup and an `PHP` page displaying player high-scores, and usernames.
My question is how would I go about displaying the high-scores inside the canvas once the game is over.
As well as saving the high score when the game ends.  I've looked on W3SCHOOLS site about AJAX but I'm still unsure of what codes to use inside the JavaScript file.
These are my php/script codes. or at-least the ones that are relevant:

```
// Here's the savescore.php file   
            <?php
                   include 'connect.php';

            $user_score = ($_POST['user_score']);
            $user_name = ($_POST['user_name']);

                if(mysql_query("INSERT INTO users VALUES('$user_name','$user_score')"))
                    echo "Score Successfully Saved";
                else
                    echo "Score Saving Failed";
            ?>
  // Here's some of the index.php file
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css">
            </HEAD>
            <body>     
                <div id="menu">  
                    <a class="item" href="/index.php">Home</a>
              <?php 
            include 'connect.php';
            session_start();
                    if($_SESSION['signed_in'])  
                {  
                    echo 'Hello ' . $_SESSION['user_name'] . '. Not you? <a href="signout.php">Sign out</a>';  
                    include 'chat.php';
                }  
                else  
                {  
                    echo '<a href="signin.php">Sign in</a> or <a href="signup.php">create an account</a>.';  
                } 
                ?>
                </div>
            <BODY>
            <canvas id="canvasGAMEOVER" width="800" height="599"> </canvas> 
            <script src="game.js"> </script>

// here's whats inside inside game.js... well the part I want to be able to save score
            var score = 0;
            function drawGAMEOVER() {
                }
```

I have used google and looked at tutorials for AJAX, I found tutorials and answers on how use AJAX using:

```
<form action="savescore.php">
  user_name: <input type="text" name="user_name"><br>
  user_score: <input type="text" name="user_score"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

but I am not sure if its possible to grab the 'user_name' they logged in with (displayed on the index.php page) as well as this.score (displayed inside the javascript file.)
Could anyone tell me how this is possible... if not maybe a better way of doing this?
Any help/reply is much appreciated thanks in advance.

Comment: are you using the jquery library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[jQuery](http://jquery.com/) is a javascript library that will greatly simplify what you are trying to do. An AJAX request is basically just like a normal web request, except it is performed asynchronously with javascript within your browser. In jQuery, you would do something like the following:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "savescore.php",
  type: "post",
  data: {
    user_score: score,
    user_name: "fake_user"
  },
  success: function() {
    console.log("Finished uploading score");
  }
});
```

Comment: I was actually just about to edit and post that I've tried using an $.ajax function, but it doesn't like the $ variable.. I'm assuming because I am using javascript and not jQuery. I have a lot of code inside my game, would i need to re-write it all in jQuery?.. I only know how to use javascript i know jQuery is a library of javacript, but I have never used a library before. So sorry if I am asking an obvoius question

Comment: you can keep the javascript in tact and just add the jQuery library

Comment: jQuery is a javascript library. It only provides additional functions, and does not conflict with vanilla (pure) javascript. You can simply include the jQuery library as Smith says

Comment: How secure is this? I think everyone can do this from console so they can easily "write" new highscores. Am I right?

Answer (score 2):

AJAX (short for `Asynchronous Javascript And XML` ) is a javascript object through which you can send requests to the webserver and get back its response asynchronously. Most of the modern browser support initializing AJAX requests via

```
var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
```

Here is how you send a request

```
xmlHttp.open('GET' , 'file_in_server.php', false);
```

'GET' may be any other type of requests (like 'POST', 'PUT'...) and 'file_in_server.php' is the file where you send request, and `false`means you are doing it synchronously.

After that line, you can write:

```
xmlHttp.send();
```

which sends the request you `open()`ed previously.

Now, the server sends back the response which you can capture by

```
var response = xmlHttp.responseText
```

Now response is anything echoed by your `file_in_server.php`

You can make use of asynchrous nature of AJAX. here's the sample code.

```
var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(xmlHttp.readyState==4 && xmlHttp.status == 200){
        var capturedText = xmlHttp.responseText;
    }
};
xmlHttp.open('GET','file.php?a=1&b=2', true); //sends GET requests, with querystring.
xmlHttp.send();
```

The above code is asynchronous in nature. It does not block other script execution. The first line creates the XMLHttpRequest object On the second line, we are just creating an event listner that says that when the ready state of xmlHttp object is changes the function should be executed. . Now the execution goes to `xmlHttp.open` which initializes the process of requesting the server. This statement makes the XMLHttpRequest know that the request is asynchronous. after that the request is sent. As soon as the request is sent, the readystate of the object is changed, and the function above is called. That function checks for two condition, readystate of the object and returned status code and if the readystate is 4 (which means, ready), and the staus is 200 (which means OK), then it catches the response in the variable. Now you can use that variable to fulfill your motive.

if your file.php echoes the username currently logged in, then that will be catched in the variable capturedText

Answer (score 0):

I don't like doing ajax without jQuery so I will give you an example with that.

Link to jQuery however you want... The easiest but not my prefered way:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
```

Create a function that can be fired from game over function...

```
function drawHighScore(){
    $.post('gethighscores.php', function(data){
    r = JSON.parse(data);

    $.each(r, function(k, v){
        context.fillText(k+":"+v, x, y);
        context.stroke();
    });
});
```

Your gethighscores.php (simplified)...

```
query for name and score and then

while ($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){ //***
$response[$r['name']] = $r['score'];
}

echo json_encode($response);
```

***Study on PDO for the query/fetch functions.